# Dragging Down Skipping Rows

Tags: excel

I have been working on this for the past several hours. I have researched other post and cannot get my issue fixed. I would like to copy a formula in cell G4 and drag down inputting the following information.
`Cell G4=M4`.
`Cell G10=M5`.
`Cell G16=M6`.
`Cell G22=M7`.
Skipping every 6 rows and so on to row 280.

Comment: use an if() with row() to multiply by 0

Comment: Not familiar with using row() and multiplying by 0

Comment: So 1 * 0 = 0. ROW() returns the row number and if it does not match a "good" one then multiply by 0.

Answer (score 0):

Neat exercise, so you can pick it apart to see what happens where - a good learning experience.

```
IF(IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(),$C$4:$C$12,0),0)>0,INDIRECT("M"&4+IFERROR(IF(ROW()=4,0,MATCH(ROW(),$C$4:$C$12,0)-1),0)),"")
```

[image]

You can also see if there is a way to reduce the length of the formulae as well as using the help column in C4:C12, which you will need to extend to get to 280.

Comment: Thank you much - after moving a few numbers around, works GREAT!!!!

Comment: Glad it works for you, just remember to accept the answer, cheers.