# How to Apply a Formula to Every Nth Column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm working on a Google Sheets file which tracks employee work hours for an entire year. The sheet has columns for employee names, start and end times, and a blank column for total work hours.

[image: Employee Work Hours Sheet]

My goal is to calculate the total work hours for each set of start and end times, without having to copy the same formula 365 times. Using a formula like `=ARRAYFORMULA(C3:C-B3:B)` only works for one column, and copying the formula for each of the remaining 364 columns is time-consuming.

I've also attempted an alternative solution of `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((MOD(COLUMN(D3:3), 4) = 0), C3:Z-B3:Z, ""))` which calculates the difference between the previous two cells in every fourth column, but if any cell in the start or finish columns has a value added to it, the formula will break (as expected) with the error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in some cell". I understand that I cannot skip non-blank cells when generating content from a single cell, but there must be other workarounds and methods to solve this problem.

Here is a link to a sample Google Sheets file where you can see the problem. There are two sheets - the first one is the problem, and the second one has one of my attempted solutions: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fk6l5JW8CSs2tPiiETX5XhzAUf0vBa_vrM3QXCFph1I/edit?usp=sharing. Feel free to view, copy, or edit the sheet.

Is there an efficient way to solve this problem? While I strongly prefer using formulas over scripts, any solution that can help me achieve my goal is welcome, including even a keyboard shortcut or a magic feature in Google Sheets that would allow me to quickly copy a formula across multiple columns.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/75565872/4961700

Comment: You could search for all of the columns that have `Total` in line two and make an Array of them and then use forEach().  That would make it possible to change the spreadsheet easier without having to change the code to find the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned: *"...copying the formula for each of the remaining 364 columns is time-consuming."*  Also: *"I strongly prefer using formulas over scripts"*

To significantly reduce the time of copy-pasting the formula 364 times, try the following.

1. Copy cell `D3`
2. Select cells `H`, `L`, `P` etc
3. Paste

This way the formula will be pasted to **all selected** cells with **just one paste**.

***Notes***

- If you find selecting all cells tricky, try batches of them.
- You can also improve your formula using `=INDEX(IF(A3:A="",,C3:C-B3:B))`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately, this solution does not meet my needs. I am looking for a way to avoid the tedious and time-consuming task of manually selecting 364 cells. Additionally, having a separate formula in each cell would be inefficient, as any changes in the formula would need to be again manually updated in each cell. Instead, I am seeking a solution where I can have a single formula in one place that will automatically apply to all 365 cells.

Comment: Then you are definitely looking for a script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use Google Apps Script, then you can create a Custom Function using JavaScript.  To get to the code editor, go to Extensions -> Apps Script.  There you will see a sample function that looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {

}
```

You would change myFunction to something like:

```
function TotalWorkHours(startTime, finishTime) {
    return finishTime - startTime;
}
```

Then you can reference it in your spreadsheet like this:

```
=TotalWorkHours(B3, C3)
```

You'll still have to paste that custom function into the 365 places, but then if your formula changes, you only have to update the formula in the script, not in all 365 places.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution added to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fk6l5JW8CSs2tPiiETX5XhzAUf0vBa_vrM3QXCFph1I/edit#gid=782579706):

1. you are just going to fill your manual data(Name, Start_time, end_time) in Sheet 1
2. the single formula in `Cell A2` of Sheet 2 will populate the entire manual data + calculated fields

currently the formula loops through `44` sets of fields (one set=start,end,total,blank_column). You can change the `44` number to your choice within the `sequence(44)` part of the formula.

```
=reduce({"Name";indirect(address(3,column(),4,,"Sheet 1 - The Problem")&":"&address(60,column(),4))},sequence(44),lambda(r,c,
{r,{"Start";indirect(address(3,index(sequence(1,44,2,4),,c),4,,"Sheet 1 - The Problem")&":"&address(60,index(sequence(1,44,2,4),,c),4))},
{"Finish";indirect(address(3,index(sequence(1,44,3,4),,c),4,,"Sheet 1 - The Problem")&":"&address(60,index(sequence(1,44,3,4),,c),4))},

{"Total";map(indirect(address(3,index(sequence(1,44,3,4),,c),4,,"Sheet 1 - The Problem")&":"&address(60,index(sequence(1,44,3,4),,c),4)),indirect(address(3,index(sequence(1,44,2,4),,c),4,,"Sheet 1 - The Problem")&":"&address(60,index(sequence(1,44,2,4),,c),4)),lambda(x,y,if(len(x),x-y,IFERROR(1/0))))},

{"";indirect(address(3,index(sequence(1,44,5,4),,c),4,,"Sheet 1 - The Problem")&":"&address(60,index(sequence(1,44,5,4),,c),4))}}))
```

[image]

Comment: I greatly appreciate the effort you put into your response! However, the current solution does not quite meet my needs as I am looking for a solution that does not require me to create another sheet. Also, Could you please provide more information about how your function works? I will review it in detail later and try to understand it better, but having some input from you as the author of the formula would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: think of it like an ongoing sequence which has 4 steps. * pull `Column 2_Start` data from original sheet * pull `Column 3_Finish` data from original sheet * pull both `Column 2_Start` AND  `Column 3_Finish` data then apply `FINISH-START` * pull `Column 5_all blanks`  *first sequence complete and it moves on to iterate next column set. Now this sequence is repeated `N` number of times mentioned in formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will keep that in mind as I decipher the function to better understand whats going on there. By the way, do you know is it possible to modify the function to work within the same sheet instead of creating a new one?

Comment: sorry..... nope

Answer (score 0):

A basic AppsScript loop

```
function writeFormulas() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var numEmployees = sheet.getLastRow() - 2;
  for(var i = 4; i<= lastCol; i+=4){
    sheet.getRange(3,i,numEmployees).setFormulaR1C1('=R[0]C[-1]-R[0]C[-2]');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes my solution. In order to avoid scripts, and knowing the limitations of ARRAYFORMULAS to expand differently in each direction; but thanks to your visual layout, what I'd do is use your 1:1 row to have a formula copied over. This way, you create the formula in A1 and copy-paste it to the whole 1:1 row; when it's the 4th column it will create the header TOTAL (do not write it yourself) and will do the calculations with OFFSET as you tried too:

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMN(A1),4)=0,{"";"TOTAL";BYROW(OFFSET($A$1,2,COLUMN(A1)-3):OFFSET($A$1,ROWS(A:A)-1,COLUMN(A1)-2),LAMBDA(each,IF(COUNTA(each),INDEX(each,,2)-INDEX(each,,1),"")))},"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution, it's a very neat one indeed! However, I'm afraid I cannot accept it as the solution for my question as it still requires the function to be applied to every relevant column. I'm starting to realize that there may not be a straightforward solution to achieve what I want.

Comment: The idea is that you just paste it in all row 1, you don't have to paste it in specific columns

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper row.

If( $row = 4, total, "").
auto fill down and across.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).